# EVM assembly level debugger

Tags: evm, assembly

I want to examine behavior of some EVM instructions in live mode, but can't find any tools like debuggers/emulators which give nice look of stack and memory and ability to execute contract by steps.

Comment: Have you tried Remix? It will let you step over code and see quite a bit of the EVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rob-hitchens pointed out, Remix has needed functionality - under Debugger section I've found everything I needed.